# While loop not looping correctly

Tags: java

Everyone in my class rn works for them perfectly fine but for me isn't working, it display "Column -1 Line -1" no matter what number I put in

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][]lista={{9,10,11,12,17},
                  {1,2,3,4,18},
                  {13,14,15,16,19},
                  {5,6,7,8,20}};
    int numuser;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int fila=-1,columna=-1;
    System.out.println("introduce el numero a buscar entre 1 y 20");
    numuser=sc.nextInt();
    boolean encontrado=false;
    
    while(i<4 && !encontrado) {
        while(j<5 && !encontrado) {
            if(numuser==lista[i][j]) {
                encontrado = true;
                fila = i;
                columna = j;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Estaba en la fila "+fila+" y en la columna "+columna);
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate `j` to `5` on the first inner loop iteration, but never set it back to `0` for the outerloop that iterates on `i`.  You can move `int j = 0` to the outer loop in order to reset the value before the inner loop:

```
while (i < 4 && !encontrado) {
    int j = 0; //Move this here
    while (j < 5 && !encontrado) {
        if (numuser == lista[i][j]) {
            encontrado = true;
            fila = i;
            columna = j;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

**Test Run:**

```
introduce el numero a buscar entre 1 y 20
20
Estaba en la fila 3 y en la columna 4
```

Note that it says 3 and 4 instead for row and column instead 4 and 5 since it is going off of the 0 indexed value, add one to both values if want to display the actual row and column value that the number is located at.